# SQL - for each id, count how many entries in one column is greater than another

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Suppose I have a table 'results' that looks like this:

```
student | score | passing_grade
1 | 50 | 70
1 | 30 | 50
2 | 90 | 50
2 | 80 | 100
```

I want to count, for each student, how many tests they've passed. The result should be as followed:

```
student | passed
1 | 0
2 | 1
```

explanation: student 1 has passed none of the tests, while student 2 has passed 1 out of 2 tests based on the conditions of the second and third column.

I don't know if it makes a difference but I created results by merging 2 tables together. I've tried to use the WHERE clause to find all rows where the score > passing_grade but I don't know if that is in the right direction. I've also tried the  COUNT(CASE WHEN score > passing_grade THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right since this counts every row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `COUNT` logic is basically correct *except* that the `ELSE` non null value is causing every record to be counted as one.  The `COUNT` function ignores only nulls, so the `ELSE` value should either be null or `ELSE` should be omitted entirely:

```sql
SELECT student, COUNT(CASE WHEN score > passing_grade THEN 1 END) AS passed
FROM results
GROUP BY student;
```

Note that MySQL supports summing boolean expressions directly, so we can make the above even tighter:

```sql
SELECT student, SUM(score > passing_grade) AS passed
FROM results
GROUP BY student;
```

Comment: This one has worked for me, thank you Tim! I completely forgot to add the group by clause.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple SQL query. I would recommend reading SQL basics and trying a bit before posting a question. But since you're a new contributor here (welcome aboard ), including the query which might help:

```sql
SELECT
    student,
    count(*) as passed
FROM results
WHERE 
    score > passing_grade
GROUP BY
    student
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT C.STUDENT,
SUM(
   CASE
     WHEN C.SCORE>=C.PASSING_GRADE THEN 1
   ELSE 0
   END
 )AS PASSED
FROM RESULTS AS C
GROUP BY C.STUDENT
```

The same logic, but with SUM-function